# Remove a string word + seperator with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string line

```
"Arvydas,(g. 1964 m. gruodžio 19 d. Kaune) – Lietuvos krepšininkas,"
```

I need to remove a specific word decided with Console.ReadLine() along with the special character that follows it - " .,!?:;()' " from the string line

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();
        string text = "Arvydas,(g. 1964 m. gruodžio 19 d. Kaune) – Lietuvos krepšininkas,";
        Regex.Replace(text, " ", ".,!?:;()'" );
```

Comment: Your code won't work, you are not even using the `word` anywhere in the code. Also, the `Regex.Replace` won't change the `text`, you need to assign the new value to `text`.

Comment: What is the desired result string, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to test your regex: https://regex101.com/r/WDOqRc/2

Then the code becomes:

```
    string word = Console.ReadLine();
    string text = "Arvydas,(g. 1964 m. gruodžio 19 d. Kaune) – Lietuvos krepšininkas,";
    text = Regex.Replace(text, $"{word}[.,!?:;()']?", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get rid of special characters (I suggest special character is *any* one except *letter*, *digit* or *apostroph*):

```
  string text = "Arvydas,(g. 1964 m. gruodžio 19 d. Kaune) – Lietuvos krepšininkas,";

  // Arvydas g 1964 m gruodžio 19 d Kaune Lietuvos krepšininkas  
  string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\W-[']]+", " ");
```

Then let's remove the `word`:

```
 string word = "Kaune"; 

 // removing word
 result = Regex
   .Replace(result, "\\b" + Regex.Escape(word) + "\\b", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 // removing double spaces if any
 result = Regex
   .Replace(result, "\\s{2,}", " ");

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 Arvydas g 1964 m gruodžio 19 d Lietuvos krepšininkas
```

Or wrapping it into a routine:

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();

string text = "Arvydas,(g. 1964 m. gruodžio 19 d. Kaune) – Lietuvos krepšininkas,";

string text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\W-[']]+", " ");

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word)) {
  text = Regex
    .Replace(text, "\\b" + Regex.Escape(word) + "\\b", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  text = Regex
    .Replace(text, "\\s{2,}", " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the mini-lesson, was a big help.